# Как поменять цвет ранее активной кнопки?

Tags: java, android, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, есть желтые кнопки, но как поменять цвет кнопки, если она уже была нажата например на зеленый??

Суть в чем, кнопки имеют обычный свой желтый цвет, но я хотел бы, что бы например после перехода по кнопке, она меняла цвет.

Android Studio

```
Button knopkaurok44;

knopkaurok44 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.knopkaurok44);
knopkaurok44.setOnClickListener(this);

case R.id.knopkaurok44:
    intent = new Intent(this, Urok44.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
default:
    break;



<Button
    android:id="@+id/knopkaurok44"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/knopkaurok29"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/knopkaurok29"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/knopkaurok29"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border_style2"
    android:text="@string/Text44"
    tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />
```

Comment: button.setBackgroundColor....

Comment: Если у вас 50 кнопок или даже 100, вам нужно посмотреть в сторону RecyclerView. Конкретнее GridLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView это хорошо, если вам нужны переключаемые кнопки, используйте `ToggleButton`. Через [`shape`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/shape.php) сформируйте включённую и отключённу кнопку (на скрине у вас градиент, значит градиент):

background_button_off.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/colorYellowGradientBackgroundEnd"
        android:startColor="@color/colorYellowGradientBackgroundStart" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

background_button_on.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/colorGreenGradientBackgroundEnd"
        android:startColor="@color/colorGreenGradientBackgroundStart" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Дальше делаем state_list:

state_list_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button_with_solid" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorButtonNotActive" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Всё что выше, кладём в res/drawable.
Цвета я думаю знаете как добавлять, ели нет, замените их просто их значение RGB, например старт: #7F94FE (взял рендомный набор значений, подберите свои взависимости от нужных оттенков).

Добавляем её в фон кнопки:

И теперь при нажатии кнопка будет менять цвет на вкл/вкл. И вы смжете получить из неё значение состояния, вроде: getChecked(). Точно не помню уже.
У этой кнопки есть такой параметры:

```
android:textOff="OFF"
android:textOn="ON"
```

При нажатии она меняет значение надписи.

Ну и теперь её можно засунуть в адаптер RecycleView и он их тебе на генерет столько сколько нужно, и вам не нужно будет думать о обработки переключения.

P.S. Кода много, но ничего здесь сложного нет, применение такой реализации приблизит вас не только визуально к правильному написанию приложений, но и практически. `shape (фигуры) и state_list` применяются в андроиде на каждом шагу.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться с этим кодом))))